# Why do I see spikes in response time when thread group is ending its execution?

Tags: html, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

My test goes for 3 hours.
Two particular thread groups(Ultimate Thread Group) out of 10 are set in such a way that load is generated in 3 sets by each of them. Both thread groups follow identical load generation pattern and both goes on for little less than 2 hours as shown in following picture, while rest of the threads groups continue to execute for remaining time.
[image: Load Model for both ultimate thread groups]

But why do I see spikes in response times when these three sets are ending.
However, the response time remains low in overall duration of the test.
[image: Response Times]

Similar spikes are seen in another thread group at the end of the test.
I have tried increasing the shutdown time of the thread groups from 10 seconds to 30 seconds. But no help so far. On going through details in JMeter, it was sure that when the load starts to go down or execution of the threads tends to end for the those two particular thread groups, then only we see spikes in response time.
I am using Jmeter 5.0

Comment: I changed the version of JMeter and executed the same test on version 3.3. Spikes are not visible anymore. Is there an issue known or unknown with JMeter 5.0?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely seeing the effect of forcibly shut down threads that are still in flight at the end of the test run. see
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/XAsUHsrJEDw

If possible, consider adding a rampdown to your test plan.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul.
I increased the shutdown time too. But still same effect haunts my results. I executed the same test with version 3.2. And it worked fine there.

Answer (score 0):

Given the very high response time of hundreds of seconds this is likely an artifact of the threads been shutdown before all the responses came back. Given the charts, i suggest using a 30-60 seconds shutdown time to insure enough padding.

Comment: Hi David,
I increased the ramp down time to 30 seconds but still I saw same results. However, it was not visible when I executed the same test with JMeter 3.2.
Not sure if its version specific issue or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this as well using v5.1.1 with the 'Ultimate Thread Group' OR the 'Standard Thread Group' when using a schedule duration.

It occurs when using a Transaction Controller with 'Generate parent Sample' selected.
Un-checking this appears to resolve the problem. This however is not ideal as I have far too many sampler results (hence the reason clicking 'Generate parent Sample' to achieve aggregated transaction results only)

[Response Times - High At End of Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ7iK.png)

[Transaction Controller - Generate Parent Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgXtm.png)

Comment: If this really is the case, then it could be a bug in the tool itself. Have you tried to apprise JMeter team of this observation?

Comment: No... How would i go about that?

Comment: Did you 'Generate parent Sample' checked on your test?